# android status bar notyfication icon

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar

I'm trying to set an icon to the status bar, I can not view it as soon as you click on the button.
The problem there is the option to delete. I want to set up so you will not be deleted as long as those entering the application and delete

```
 public void setNotificationToStatusBar(){
      Intent intent= new Intent(this, PrefActivitySmsForwarder.class);
      PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,intent, 0);
      String forwarder_start_str= getResources().getString(R.string.sms_forwarding_activated);
      String app_name=getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
      Notification n= new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,forwarder_start_str, System.currentTimeMillis());
      n.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), app_name, forwarder_start_str, pi);
      n.defaults= Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
      nm.notify(uniqueId, n);
      finish();

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I create a notification. Using setOngoing(true) I make it persistent

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setOngoing(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setOngoing%28boolean%29)

```
Intent intent = new Intent("MY_INTENT");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                                .setContentTitle("Title")
                                .setContentText("Click here")
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.img2)
                                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img1))
                                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                                .setOngoing(true)
                                .build();
```

If you want to keep your own way of creating the notification and not use the Notification.Builder, you could add this line of code to edit the flag field of the notification

```
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
```

Comment: not work, i see need use FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT but eclipse not give me this option

Answer (score 0):

```
      String forwarder_start_str= getResources().getString(R.string.sms_forwarding_activated);
      String app_name=getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
      Intent intent= new Intent(this, PrefActivitySmsForwarder.class);
      Notification n= new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,forwarder_start_str, System.currentTimeMillis());

     /** I ADD THIS **/ n.flags=Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
      PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,intent,0);
      n.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), app_name, forwarder_start_str, pi);
      n.defaults= Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
      nm.notify(uniqueId, n);
      finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this too

```
    int icon = R.drawable.icon_notification;


    String msg= "hey";

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,Activity.class);

    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                                                                .setSmallIcon(icon)
                                                                .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                                                                .setContentIntent(intent)
                                                                .setPriority(PRIORITY_LOW) 
                                                                .setContentText(msg)
                                                                .setAutoCancel(true)
                                                                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND   | 
                                                                             Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | 
                                                                             Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS);


    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: I can set even after turning off and turn on the phone icon still stays?

Comment: if you want the icon to stay use startForeground(notificationId, mBuilder.build());